# Symfony2 How to set data on a submitted form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am facing a tricky issue with one of my form.

The underlying objects (entities) are pretty simple: Work ManyToOne Artist.

Working on the WorkType form, my UI makes the field `artist` useless as I always do `$work->setArtist($artist)` before building the form with my filled object `$work`. Everything is OK. Thus, I have no `artist` field in this form. My form contains some fields that depend on the underlying `artist` value, hence I must set the artist before form is submitted (and not after).

Now I am making a MasterType form in which I embed a WorkType. This time I cannot set the artist before building the form, as the artist results of the submitted data of MasterType.

My question is: how can I set the artist to the underlying object of my embedded WorkType?

It has to be after MasterType is submitted, because the artist depends on the submitted data, but before WorkType is submitted, because the WorkType form contains fields depending on the artist.

I have tried to hack several events with no success so far. Using the SUBMIT event on the MasterType, I could not set data on the embedded WorkType without facing a "You cannot set data on a submitted form".

Many thanks for any insights!

Comment: Please show some code. e.g. your form types and the controller :)

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 0):

how about FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT on WorkType ?

Comment: pre_submit only allows me to work on form fields, I can't manipulate the underlying object, thus can't do `$underlyingObject->setArtist($artist)`. One way would be to add this `artist` field, but it seems like a hack...

Comment: Easy way then: add artist field as hidden in Work Type.